# Bintray add to JCenter: The Version Control <url> returns 404

Tags: android, maven, bintray, jcenter

I'm trying to create a [Maven repository](https://bintray.com/ivangarzab/mixhalo-sdk/com.mixhalo.sdk) through Bintray that is part of JCenter.  I have already uploaded my library by following [this guide](https://github.com/umeshbsa/android-library-publish-maven-jcenter#create-account), but when I click on the button that says "Add to JCenter" and follow the prompts, I get an error that reads:

> Failed to send message: The Version Control <url> returns 404

I'd like to know why this is failing and how am I supposed to set up the VC URL if not the way I've done already.

A few things to add which I believe could be the cause of the problems:

- My Bintray account is not connected to GitHub (I can change this, but gotta talk to the people above first)
- My GitHub repo is private (Ideally, we don't change this option)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [Bintray Documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/BT/Importing+from+GitHub), you must have the premium plan to access private repositories

> Note that private repositories in GitHub are only displayed and available for importing by Bintray users with Premium Plan accounts who also have "Access private repositories" permissions in GitHub.

If you do have the premium plan, you must give access to the private repo as well within GitHub.